# Issue uploading xml file with webclient

Tags: c#, xml, file-upload, webclient

Hey im trying to upload a XML file to a webserver using ftp and webclient. The uploading works fine but it adds the headers to the top of the xml file.
I use this code to upload the file

```
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential (ftp_username, ftp_password);
client.UploadFile (String.Format ("ftp://{0}:{1}/{2}", ftp_host, ftp_port, ftp_path), "STOR", Path.Combine (downloadLocation, "WebPermissions.xml"))
```

And when looking at the file on my webserver, the file looks like this

```
--------------8d4d10f462b8a6b
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="WebPermissions.xml"
Content-Type: text/xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RocketPermissions xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
....
....
</RocketPermissions>
```

I've been searching for a while and cant seem to find a solution. I saw a suggestion to use UploadDate instead, or using UploadString and setting the content type to text/xml but before trying those i want to know if its possible with UploadFile

Comment: a website. The file gets uploaded it just has 
--------------8d4d10f462b8a6b
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="WebPermissions.xml"
Content-Type: text/xml

Comment: Are you 100% sure that `client.UploadString (String.Format ("ftp://{0}:{1}/{2}", ftp_host, ftp_port, ftp_path), "STOR", Path.Combine (downloadLocation, "WebPermissions.xml"))` is your code? _It wouldn't result in the upload you are seeing since the payload would just be the **path** to your XML file not the contents itself https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d0d3595k(v=vs.110).aspx ._ Are you sure you aren't using `https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esst63h0(v=vs.110).aspx`?

Comment: Oh my bad let me edit, its UploadFile not UploadString that was me testing something

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it using UploadData instead

```
client.UploadData (String.Format ("ftp://{0}:{1}/{2}", ftp_host, ftp_port, ftp_path), "STOR", File.ReadAllBytes (Path.Combine (downloadLocation, "WebPermissions.xml")));
```